# Wire a bathroom fan and light so the light always controls the fan, but the fan can be operated independantly from the light

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom

I have a bathroom light fixture and a fan that are currently both independently controlled by their own switches. I'd like to wire it (preferably without having to go into the attic to change the current wiring...asbestos insulation) such that when the light comes on, the fan also comes on, but the fan can be operated independently.

```
Truth Table of desired effect
+--------------+------------+-------+-----+
| Light Switch | Fan Switch | Light | Fan |
+--------------+------------+-------+-----+
| Off          | Off        | Off   | Off |
| Off          | On         | Off   | On  |
| On           | Off        | On    | On  |
| On           | On         | On    | On  |
+--------------+------------+-------+-----+
```

The current wiring is like this for both switches.

[image]

I was thinking that there has to be some way to wire the switches together with 3 or 4-way switches in order to acheive the desired effect, but I am having trouble coming up with a solution. Thoughts?

Comment:  this is a beautifully asked question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do that with a double pole switch and a single pole normal switch.  Wire the hot to both of the line side poles on the double pole switch as well as to the single pole switch.

Wire both the fan and the light to individual poles on switched side of the double pole switch.  Then run a jumper from the pole that controls the fan on the double pole switch to the switched side of the single pole switch.  All the neutrals and grounds stay connected as they are. Don't get confused with a 3-way or 4-way switch, those are different animals.  You may have to go to an electrical supply house to get a true double pole wall switch.

I could provide a diagram if you want.   But I want to post this quickly to beat out the big 3!  LOL  Competition for points here is fierce!  LOL

[image: Double pole switch]

Carl asked me to provide more info.  This what I have time for right now. If others wanted to contribute a better diagram, that's welcome.

[image: Crude diagram of solution]

Comment: Genius! I knew I was missing something. A double pole switch would do it. Didn't even know that was a thing. Thanks!!!

Comment: Not that fierce lol.  Anyone can upvote any post :)  @Reid a Code legal, UL listed DPST switch that fits the standard form-factor is indeed a real thing, but you might not like the price LOL.

Comment: You really should specify   throws as well,  tho' it appears you are designing for a DPST.  A  DPDT can easily be purposed as a DPST by not connecting everything.   To make this answer complete, you should provide a diagram,  **and** map "3-way" and "4-way" switch names to their closest  technical   XPYT counterparts (and why they differ, i.e. internal wirings).

Comment: "Switched leg to ligh" I hate writeos... ;) Really good answer, though, very helpful

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, the price isn't too bad; you can find them for $6: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Double-Pole-Toggle-Switch-White-R52-0CSB2-2WS/202027029?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-301447162-_-202027029-_-N

Comment: @Reid and now you can substitute the SPST with a timer or motion activated switch.

Comment: @P2000, or even better, a moisture sensor -- that way, the fan won't turn off until it's finished its job.

Comment: @NateS. yes indeed. I just assumed it was organic fumes, not water vapour...

Comment: @P2000, fans are nice to have for organic fumes, yes, but in some climates, they're also critical for preventing moisture issues.  If you take a hot shower and it steams up the room, and the fan isn't on to remove it, eventually it'll soak into things you don't want it in.

Comment: @FreeMan  What "writeo"?  I don't see no stinking writeo!  LOL (fixed it). Must be frustrating for you not to be able to edit a graphic!  He he he.   Also, what a "nice" term, "organic fumes" for poo poo odor!  Gotta leave it to the Brits to be proper (figured it was a Brit due to the spelling of vapor (vapour). )